# Parsing string to Json in the Constructor

Tags: java, android

HY!!

I have a Json class, so i will parse in the constructor the json string to JSonObject.

```
    public class JSONParse extends JSONObject  {

        public JSONParse(string json) {
//pseudo code
        this.obj = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(json));
        }
    }
```

please help

Comment: pseudo code: this.obj = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(json));

Comment: Sounds like you want us to write the code for you. Check out the answer by @hilal - those links should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on what your question is, but I guess this is what you want?

```
public class JSONParse extends JSONObject  {
    public JSONParse(String json) throws JSONException {
        super(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- [json java parser](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=json+java+parser)